# Interior of the Graph of $\sin(1/x)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$. If I'm correct then the boundary of $S=\{(x,f(x)):x\in\mathbb{R}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is $\{(x,f(x)):x \text{ in domain of } f(x)\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$, since for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and an open ball $B_\varepsilon(0)$, $B_\varepsilon(0)\cap S\ne \emptyset \ne B_\varepsilon(0)\cap [S]^c$. [I have some doubts about this part though].

For the interior of $S$, it is the empty set, since there does not exist an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_\varepsilon((x,f(x)))\subset S$.

Thus, the closure of $S$ is $S\cup\{(0,0)\}$.

Please let me know if you think this is about right.

Comment: What definitions do you have for the boundary/interior/closure of a function?

Comment: Are you considering the graph of $\sin(1/x)$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Comment: @JoeDub: that's right.

Comment: @CameronBuie: the boundary of a set is the set of all points such that the intersection of any open ball centered in the boundary is not empty with the set and not empty with its complement. I.e. $B_\varepsilon(x) \cap E \ne \emptyset \ne B_\varepsilon(x) \cap E^c$. For the interior, it's the union of all open subsets of $E$. For the closure, it's the intersection of all sets containing $E$.

Comment: Yes, I know. I didn't ask about the boundary/interior/closure of a set, but rather of a *function*.

Comment: @JoeDub seems to have figured out what you're talking about. I will simply note that it is incredibly confusing to use $0$ to mean two completely different things in a single sentence, which is one source (of many) of my confusion.

Comment: I've added the notion that $f(x)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @sequence I fixed your definition. Your notation is just wrong. This is the proper way to notate the set you're interested in (also called the *graph* of a function). I'm not sure if you meant $(0,0)$ though, or some subset of the y-axis

Comment: Yes, I meant $(0,0)$, thanks for clarifying this, was too tired yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks generally right. The interior of the graph is empty, though it's boundary is $S\cup\{(0,y):y\in[-1,1]\}$. This might have been what you meant the whole time and I made a mistake when correcting your notation.

To see that this whole segment is contained in the boundary, consider a horizontal line in the plane that intersects the graph. The intersection of this line with the graph creates a sequence of points that converge to the intersection of the line with the y-axis. Alternatively, your argument holds for this extended set. Either way, you still need to argue that no other point is in the boundary. This can be done by showing that the set is closed, as closure is monotonic and a closed set is its own closure.

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean $S\cup \{(0, y): y \in [-1, 1]\}$?

Comment: @sequence  How is that any different from what I wrote? It looks like you've just changed the variable?

Comment: Considering $x$ and $y$ are dummy variables, it's not different in principle, I think. But due to the standard convention for the $y$-axis, it could be less confusing to use $y$.

Comment: That's fair. Yes, I mean the vertical strip of the y axis between $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$

Answer (score 1):

As a bit of notational touching-up, the graph of $f$ is the set $G:=\{(x,f(x)) \; : \; x \text{ in the domain of } f\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

You're correct that the interior of $G$ is empty, and the boundary of $G$ is equal to the closure of $G$.

However, I claim your closure is incorrect. It should be $G\cup\left(\{0\}\times[-1,1]\right)$ (that is, add in the whole vertical line segment from (0,-1) to (0,1) ). Your argument justifying that this is the closure/boundary should work for this larger set too, although you should change the notation for your open balls' centers to reflect the fact that you have a coordinate pair: $B_{\varepsilon}(0,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

see this one: Topologist's sine curve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve