# What are the interior and boundary of $\Bbb R^2 - \{(x,sin(1/x))|x>0\}$ in $\Bbb R^2$?

Tags: general-topology

In $\Bbb R^2$, is the interior of $\Bbb R^2 - \{(x,sin(1/x))|x>0\}$ itself? The curve is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ so its graph is closed, and hence the set is open. Moreover, its boundary is $\{(x,sin(1/x))|x>0\}$.

Am I correct?

Comment: No, the graph is not closed.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I see why the graph is not closed. Thanks.

Comment: @user546106, my mistake, I'll delete.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628757/interior-of-the-graph-of-sin1-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boundary of $$\Bbb R^2 - \{(x,sin(1/x))|x>0\}$$ is $$B=\{(x,sin(1/x))|x>0\}\cup (\{0\}\times [-1,1])$$

The interior is$$\Bbb R^2 - B$$